Laravel connection to SQL Server with Active Directory
i need to connect my Laravel app to a DB in SQL Server.
Now the "traditional" user/pass have changed to an Active Directory user for the SQL Server
I need configure correctly the config/database.php file
I have use php 7.4.19 (laravel 8.4) and sql server 2019
My connection is
'PPULSE' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('USERNAME', 'DOMAIN\user'),
            'password' => env('PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            // 'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'strict' => true,
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => true,
        ],

I use the user like DOMAIN\user
Any idea?
I tried to configure the options array like
'options'   => [
            PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => true,
            PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCRYPT => false,  // Opción según tu necesidad
            PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING => true,  // Pooling de conexiones
            'domain' => 'FCSTONE',  // Dominio NTLM
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,  // Sesiones persistentes NTLM
        ],


or like a
'options' => [
        // Otras opciones específicas de SQL Server
        'Encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'no'), // Cifrado opcional
        'TrustServerCertificate' => env('DB_TRUST_CERT', 'true'), // Confianza en el certificado del servidor
        'Authentication' => SQLSRV_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING ? null : [
            'authentication' => SQLSRV_AUTH_NTLM,
            'UID' => env('USERNAME', 'DOMAIN\user'),
            'PWD' => env('PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'Database' => env('DATABASE', 'forge'),
        ],

But PDO constants doesn't exist

You can't pass the username and password for a trusted connection in your connection string; you need to run the application as the domain user that is connecting or use impersonation.

this is an application user for the DB server, how can i pass?

As I stated, you can't. If you need to pass credentials in the connection string you need to use SQL Authentication. If the application is running as a service account, then you should be giving that service account's (domain) user access to the SQL Server and the permissions it needs to do its "job". Then you would connect using a trusted connection.

Where are you running PHP from? Windows or a Linux box, something else? Is that box joined to the domain

I'm running from Windows.
app acount is correct and it have permissions, i test from Node app with user and the connection is ok.
the problem is with php

Remove the UID and PWD options, you cna't use those with Windows Authentication. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

I have tried with the uid.txt and pwd.txt files, but it's not working

Problem Solved
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/using-always-encrypted-php-drivers?view=sql-server-ver15#using-azure-key-vault

Laravel configuration
'PPULSE' => [
'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'charset' => 'utf8',
'prefix' => '',
'options' => [
'KeyStoreAuthentication' => 'KeyVaultClientSecret',
'KeyStorePrincipalId' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'Dominio\usuario'),
'KeyStoreSecret' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
],
]
